# MySQL database design - trouble figuring out table relationships

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database, innodb

I'm trying to figure out the best way to design these tables for a website I'm making for a school club. I want to set it up so each user can have multiple emails, phone numbers, and addresses tied to their account. To do this I tried to tie all these things to a contacts table and store the contacts id in the users table as a foreign key. The contacts id is also a foreign key in the emails, phone numbers, and addresses table. Is this a feasible way of relating these tables or should I just cut out the middle man (contacts table) and store the user id in the emails, phone numbers, and addresses tables?

Just in case my description of the relationships weren't enough, here is an ERD for the tables:

[image: ERD]

Sorry for such a "noob" question, it's been a while since I had to build a database with more complexity than 2 tables. Any general tips for database design are very much welcomed as well.

Comment: The best way would be to use Table Inheritance and make them all subtypes of class AbstractAddress. Then you can query the user for all addresses easily. This is what Hay, Silverston, Fowler and others recommend.

Comment: Table inheritance is a software design pattern as discussed by Fowler (here http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) it isn't really relevant to the question which is an RDBMS schema design problem -  and a good one at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is remove the Contacts table and store the user_id in the tables on the right, rather than contact_id.

Remove contact_id from Users as well.

Comment: Unless a contact can be more than one user, I suppose.

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you have a M:N relationship it's a different story, but your question assumes you don't.

Comment: Okay, I had an inkling this is what I needed to do but I have a habit of making things more complicated than they need to be. Just for the recorded, the relationship between users and emails, phone numbers, and addresses is M:N. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I have dealt with this very question in the past. We did it wrong and we were sorry.

The determining factors should be these:

1. Will you have any other category of person that isn't a user, for whom you need to store contact information?
2. Will those kinds of persons somehow be "fungible" with users?

If you answer *both* these questions "yes," keep your contact table. Otherwise get rid of it.

The mistake made by a team I worked on was our answer to the second question. We had medical patients and doctors/nurses/etc as our categories of people. We stored their contact information together. But we shouldn't have done that because patients' contact information is very sensitive and confidential, but health care provider information is much less so.  We were always wishing we didn't have the two kinds of data in just one set of tables after the system became successful.

Unless you can convince yourself you need your contact table, get rid of it, I say!

Comment: I don't think I'll run into either problems since each user has a "status" determining their role in the club (ex. Member, President, Treasurer, etc.). I opted to get rid of the contact table, like you suggested. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is a great point. Persons vs Contacts. (Bitter) Experience has shown me the value of the approach outlined here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I would cut out the midle man:

Although I was tempted to go the 'contact_type' route, I have found that there are usually validations and different data types which become more complicated when the contact is generic.  For instance a table that has address fields is not the same as a phone number and having both presents more complexity and less readability.

This model focuses on simplicity, e.g. a user has many emails and an email belongs ot a user.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to me you can design DB accordingly

```
Table 1 : Users
UserID //PK
Name

Table 2 : Contacts
ContactID  //PK
UserID  //FK to Users
ContactTypeID   // FK to ContactType
Value

Table 3 : ContactType
ContactTypeID   //PK
ContactTypeName
Description
```

Table 1 is pretty clear stores user information
Table 3 holds information about contacttype i.e email, home phone, mobile, home address, shipping address, etc
Table 2 holds information about user, contact type and its value
like cinatacttypeid corresponds to mobile than value is , etc.

Comment: This is an interesting approach to storing the data. ContactType becomes a generic container for any type of contact information. The main problem I see with it, though, is if a contact type has more than one field, like an address.

Comment: Contact.Type.Description can be an address? No validations or formatting unless we have separate fields... which we wouldn't need for email addresses.

Comment: This generic container does help me with another design problem I'm having in another table though. :D

Technically couldn't a hierarchy relationship between a ContactType and a more specific version of a ContactType be made to make this work? I remember reading about these types of relationships a while back, but don't remember how to implement them. Out of curiosity, do you have any idea how to implement such a relationship?